# jquery alter submit on way to server

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two fields on a form, both are input boxes with the same value in them when the page is loaded, one is hidden.

when the user hits submit, I want to check the boxes and if the value is not different, I want to set the value of the visible box to "" (empty string).

Here is my code (it is iterating over a set of inputs but the basics are what i've described)

```
$(".edit_functional_area").submit(function() {        
    $(".value_shown").each(function(i, obj) {
        var hidden_obj = $(this).next();
        if (hidden_obj.val() == $(this).val() && $(this).val() != "") {
            alert($(this).val());

            $(this).val("");

            alert($(this).val());
        }
    });
});
```

Visually, the field is in fact getting blanked out but on the server, in my controller (this is in a rails app) the params comes through with the value still set.

what I want, is for that value to be blank in the params coming to the server so my model doesn't add the values to the database when it doesn't need to.

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Maybe `return false;`will stop the submit from taking place ;)

Comment: I suspect the data changes in the event handler aren't reaching the data being sent to the server. What about replacing the submit handler with a `click` handler that changes the data, then fires a `submit` event when it's done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/10569/andrewdotnich - I tried this for a while and it seemed like it might get me there but the ultimate solution was closer to my old code.  thanks for the hand though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got this working.

removed the hidden field as the way I created it was causing an ID conflict in the html.
instead I used a data attr in the input box to set the old value and use that to compare against in the jquery.

also had to change the command that was altering the value of the element to use attr(field, value) rather than val(value) to make the change.

```
$(".edit_functional_area").submit(function(event) {
    $(".value_shown").each(function(i, obj) {
        var data = $(this).attr('data');
        if (parseFloat(data) == parseFloat($(this).val()) && $(this).val() != '') {
            $(this).attr('value', '');
        }
    });
});
```

thanks for the suggestions!
Max